# Traceback in Lagrange Interpolation code in Python

Tags: python

[image: Lagrange Interpolation code]

Can someone please explain where I went wrong? I used the same code for a different problem where i had to create arrays from the given specifications, but i dont understand where this code went wrong.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

#### I think your problem is that you haven't quite got straight what your variables mean.

In the function definition, you use Xp to mean a single value.
You also define it as a single value.

However just before you call the function, you treat it as though it was a list:

```
[ F(X,Y,i) for i in Xp ]
```

One fix would be to set Xp = [302], not 302.

#### Preventing future similar errors

Even better would be to use a more mnemonic variable name, such as Xp_list, so that you don't fall into a similar trap in future. In my code I would typically call those variables:

```
x_list
y_list
xp_list
```

Or

```
xs
ys
xps
```